# Why does Eclipse's debugger stop working randomly?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have been working on a project that requires rigorous debugging at each step, and I notice that my debugger just randomly stops working from time to time and does not respond to any of the breakpoints.

I tried restarting eclipse and unplugging my device over and over. Any particular reason this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would make sure your Eclipse is not running out of heap space memory. If necessary, increase the heap memory using the `-mx` Java command line flag.

In `<Eclipse root folder>\eclipse.ini` change `-Xmx384m` to `-Xmx768m`, this will double the available heap space for Eclipse and hopefully improve its stability.

Answer (score 2):

For all major issues with eclipse, not loading, freezing, or debugger failure (that is not because of your code), try the following line:

```
./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState -refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

-xms is the start memory (at the VM start), -xmx is the maximum memory for the VM

```
eclipse.ini : the memory for the VM running eclipse
jre setting : the memory for java programs run from eclipse
catalina.sh : the memory for your tomcat server
```